# Calculating the time complexity of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to calculate the time complexity of this algorithm that determines if a positive integer N can be expressed as x^y. The algorithm's author is [Vaibhav Gupta](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-number-can-be-expressed-as-xy-x-raised-to-power-y/).

```
// Returns true if n can be written as x^y
bool isPower(unsigned int n)
{
    // Base case
    if (n <= 1) return true;

    // Try all numbers from 2 to sqrt(n) as base
    for (int x=2; x<=sqrt(n); x++)
    {
        unsigned  p = x;

        // Keep multiplying p with x while is smaller
        // than or equal to x
        while (p <= n)
        {
            p *= x;
            if (p == n)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The author says that this algorithm is an optimized version of the first one which is:

```
// Returns true if n can be written as x^y
bool isPower(unsigned n)
{
    if (n==1)  return true;

    // Try all numbers from 2 to sqrt(n) as base
    for (int x=2; x<=sqrt(n); x++)
    {
        unsigned y = 2;
        unsigned p = pow(x, y);

        // Keep increasing y while power 'p' is smaller
        // than n. 
        while (p<=n && p>0)
        {
            if (p==n)
                return true;
            y++;
            p = pow(x, y);
         }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Does this first one has a different time complexity since he uses the pow function?

Comment: For me this is very strange that there are no check `if (n % x != 0) continue;` right before `while`. Is there any reason to avoid this optimization?

Comment: @ilya - The question is not about that.  It is about the complexity of the algorithm *as written*.

Answer (score 2):

When it returns false, the algorithm tries increasing powers of all integers `x`, until they exceed `n`. The search stops after `x = √n` has been tried.

So for a rough evaluation, evaluating the powers until `x^d = n` takes about `log n/log x` multiplies, and is repeated from `x=2` to `x=√n`.

Hence the complexity is like

```
log n.Sum(x=2 to √n)1/log x
```

which is uneasy to estimate, but `O(log n.√n)` and `Ω(√n)`.

The `pow` version takes `log d` multiplies instead of `1` to compute a power, provided it does so by repeated squarings. As `d = log n/log x`, the complexity is like

```
log n.Sum(x=2 to √n)(log log n - log log x)/log x
```

even harder to estimate, but `O(log n.log log n.√n)` and `Ω(√n)`.

For the range of `n` covered by the int type, you can expect the `pow` version to be between one time and five times slower (unless the `pow` function has a big overhead).

Comment: Sum(x=2 to √n)1/log x ~= √n / log(√n) so the complexity is O(√n). (http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=89138 for details of the sum).

Comment: @PaulHankin: thanks. That confirms O(log n.√n) and Ω(√n). :)

Comment: I think it's nice to find a tight bound here, because it motivates the more careful analysis that you've done here, and shows that the naive approach of approximation in the other answer gives the wrong answer. Anyway, I upvoted :)

Comment: @PaulHankin: if I am right, the complexity of the slower algorithm can be addressed by the same method. The extra factor should be `log log n`, or lower.

Comment: Yes, the second algorithm is somewhere between O(√n) and O(√n log log n), and the exact expression isn't of any practical value given how slowly log log n grows.

Comment: The estimate of the first sum is confirmed by the the integral of 1/ln(x), which is known as the logarithmic integral, with asymptotic behavior x/ln(x). Then the complexity is indeed Θ(√n).

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the outer loop is square root of n, and the inner loops are in the order of log n (since the number grows exponentially) so your complexity should be something in the tune of

```
  O(sqrt(n)*log n)
```

Comment: The inner loop runs log_x(n) times (log_x being log base x). Why is it valid to ignore the changing base when doing the summation?

Comment: @PaulHankin Yes it is because you can turn any log base A of x into a log base b of x by simply multiplying by a constant  http://www.mathwords.com/c/change_of_base_formula.htm and constant multipliers go away with big-O notation :)

Comment: @PaulHankin I answered a similar question a while back :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314337/is-this-function-in-the-complexity/6314497#6314497

Comment: @Rob I see what you mean, but the complexity involves summing over these changing bases, and the method is incorrect (and produces the wrong answer overall). Yves' answer below uses a correct approach.